# Julia PyCall's @pyimport causes ** incremental compilation may be broken for this module ** warning

Tags: python, julia

My problem can be reduced the following example of a Module

```
__precompile__(true)

module Temp

using PyCall

import Base: find, getindex

export f

@pyimport zipfile

function f(dir::String)
    zipfile.ZipFile(fzip)[:extract]("somefileinsidezip.txt", dir)
end

end
```

when I **save this module to the file** `Temp.jl` load it with

```
using Temp
```

it gives me warning:

```
WARNING: eval from module __anon__ to Temp:    
Expr(:toplevel, Expr(:const, :BadZipfile = PyCall.PyObject ... )::Any
  ** incremental compilation may be broken for this module **
```

Any ideas about what am I doing wrong?

And what is the solution?

Comment: Need more info. Works for me on 0.5,0.6,0.7 on macOS. Try `Pkg.update("PyCall")`.

Comment: @Isaiah Save the module Temp on a separate file, and then load it with using Temp, then you should get the warning

Comment: https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl#using-pycall-from-julia-modules last paragraph.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks you!